# Editable cells and non editable cells in one tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want a uitableview where its first four cells are not editable but last cells are editable, we could able to delete or swap cells with other editable cells. Also keep that in mind that we could not able to swap editable cells with non editable cells. swap must be working within editable cells only. How can I achieve this with only 1 tableview.

Following image can give its demonstration.

[Demonstration of my idea in image form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8ytI.png)

thanks in advance.

Comment: take a deeper look on the __[`UITableViewDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource)__ and its `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool` or optionally the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool` methods to make the UX more sophistocated; these will be your solution.

Comment: I was so easy. I wasn't expecting this as a piece of cake. Thank you so much Sir. :)